# Odd collection view scrolling behaviour with UITextField in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uitextfield

I have a `UICollectionView` with some `UICollectionViewCells` that contain `UITextFields`. When a `UITextField` is selected for editing, the keyboard shows and the `UICollectionView` moves up accordigly to make the active `UITextField` visible. I am relying on default behaviour with this and the `UITextField` is actually appropriately positioned when `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` is launched. However, right after that, the `UICollectionView` will scroll automatically back to the top, and the `UITextField` will move out of view (behind keyboard).

What could be causing this and how could I debug this behaviour? Please note, that any custom code for `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` like `scrollRectToVisible` or Apple's sample code will not help, as the scrolling off viewable areas happens at a later stage overriding that code. I am just unable to pinpoint the cause of this.

EDITED to add:

An animation to show how the view behaves with a hard keyboard (iPad Pro) when clicking Next to cycles fields. This works fine.

[image: An animation to show how the view behaves with a hard keyboard (iPad Pro) when clicking Next to cycles fields.]

An animation to show how the view behaves with a soft keyboard when clicking Next to cycles fields. Here the keyboard avoiding does not work.

[image: An animation to show how the view behaves with a soft keyboard when clicking Next to cycles fields.]

Comment: Use TPKeyboardAvoiding 3rd party that already have class for `UICollectioView`

Comment: Thank you for proposing this. I should have mentioned I am targeting iOS 10, and as you must be aware, since iOS 9 there has been automatic keyboard avoiding for UICollectionView. For this reason TPKeyboardAvoiding will disable itself when on iOS 9 or never. I removed this check to try it, and it performs worse than the default avoidance.

Comment: What I would really appreciate are recommendations how to debug UICollectionView scroll events, so I could pinpoint what code is triggering the unwanted scrolling that messes up with the positioning after it initially appears correct.

Comment: I am presenting the collection view on modally presented form. I am thinking this behaviour might have something to do with the way I am setting up the content size form the form or the way the cells are layed out.